# Getting strings from EditText fields using a recycler view / object

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-edittext

I'm having trouble understanding how I can get the values entered in multiple edit text fields into one array.

Here is my code:

```
    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    protected EditText editText;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        editText = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.editid);

        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                editModelArrayList.get(getAdapterPosition()).setEditTextValue(editText.getText().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });

    }

}

        for (int i = 0; i < CustomAdapter.editModelArrayList.size(); i++){

        tv.setText(tv.getText() + " "+ CustomAdapter.editModelArrayList.get(i).getEditTextValue());

    }
```

What I'd like to do is to use this code CustomAdapter.editModelArrayList.get(i).getEditTextValue()); to get all the values in one string and then go from there, but when I do this I only get the value entered in the last text field.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of member variable `editText`, create a final local variable and use that in listener:

```
final EditText editText2 = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.editid);

editText2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
.
.
.
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        editModelArrayList.get(getAdapterPosition()).setEditTextValue(editText2.getText().toString());
    }
```